# Submit FormData with ajaxForm plugin

Tags: jquery, forms, ajaxform, form-data

How to put FormData object into a form and submit it by using ajaxForm plugin?
I'm trying to do something as below:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('photo', file);
var form = $("<form method='POST' action='url.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'></form>");
```

add the fd formData as the object to the form and convert the form into ajaxForm by:

```
form.ajaxForm({
      beforeSend: function(e) {},
      uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {},
      complete: function(data) {}
});
```

then submit the form.
So in the url.php I can fetch the file by $_FILES['photo'];

Comment: See http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2012/01/10/ridiculously-simple-ajax-uploads-with-formdata

Comment: Hm I know how to post the FormData with pure ajax, but in this case I need to post it via ajaxForm since I need the callback function such as beforeSend, uploadProgress, and complete function, which can only be implemented by ajaxForm.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly send data as like normal ajax post..

Like
..

```
form.ajaxForm({
  data: { data: fd }, 
  beforeSubmit:function() { 

    } 
  beforeSend: function(e) {},
  uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {},
  complete: function(data) {}
});
```

I have tested it and it is working fine..

Comment: I also has tried your method before, but it always return "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation", that's why I consider whether there is another method for this case?
this is my current code:

Comment: `$("#upload_file").change(function(){
    var filelist = $(this).context.files;
    for( var i = 0; i < filelist.length; ++i ) {      
      var fd = new FormData();
      fd.append('photo', filelist[i]);
      var form = $("<form method='POST' action='url.text' enctype='multipart/form-data'></form>");
      create_ajax_form(form, fd);
    }
}
function create_ajax_form(obj, fd){
  obj.ajaxForm({
      data: { data: fd },
      beforeSend: function(e) {},
      uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {},
      complete: function(data) {}
  });
}`

Comment: I have tried it works normally with normal ajax post, I can fetch the file successfully, but didn't work with ajaxForm.

Comment: I found the problem, I just mess the ajaxForm for "data" and "formData", and it works normally after I change the "data" into "formData"

Answer (score 0):

That's what is working for me

```
var fd = new FormData(this);
fd.append('upload', file);

$(this).ajaxSubmit({
    formData: fd,
    ...
});
```